# How can I unlock my s6 Edge Lock Screen w/o having to factory reset it?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, lock-screens, google-account, locked-out

Given how sensitive the fingerprint sensor on this phone, the 5 tries were used and the phone was asking for the backup password after. The problem is that i cant even remember the PW. I can unlock it using my google account But I can't even enable my WiFi or MD.  What's the best way to do?

PLEASE HELP!! 
THANKS IN ADVANCE! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling wifi using ADB and than sign in.
As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13652723)
Enable using below script.

adb -s $PHONESERIAL shell "svc wifi enable"

You can also refer other [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10282484)